# Creating a for loop to consolidate powershell menu-driven script

Tags: powershell

I've been working on a script to install a product that requires several installers to work correctly. Some require certain features to be installed, while others are optional. My script is menu-driven, which enables the optional installers and works reasonably well.

Much of the code is re-used and I'd like to consolidate it into a single for-loop, but my PShell-foo is not yet black-belt level. I am familiar with CSV input for multi-variable for-loops, but think this can be done with an array generated in the code. Can one of you masters train this neophyte?

Here is a sanitized version of the current code:

```
# Main Level Menu Choices
switch (Read-Host $Main_Prompt)
    {
        1 {$choice = 1}
        2 {$choice = 2}
        3 {$choice = 3}
        4 {$choice = 4}
        5 {$choice = 5}
        "q" {$choice = q}
    }

if (($choice -eq "q"){
    Write-host "Exiting!"
    exit
}

# Install 1
if (($choice -eq 1) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Installing 1"
    $1Path = "$InstallSource\Folder1\file.msi"
    if (Test-Path $1Path) {
        $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "msiexec.exe"
        $processInfo.arguments = "/i `"$1Path`" /qr ARGUMENTS"
        $processMSI = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $processMSI.StartInfo = $processInfo
        $processMSI.Start() | Out-Null
        $processMSI.WaitforExit()

        if ($processMSI.ExitCode -ne 0) {
            Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processMSI.ExitCode "Exiting!"
            exit
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-host "Installer does not exist. Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}

# Install 2
if (($choice -eq 2) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Installing 2"
    $2Path = "$InstallSource\Folder2\file.msi"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "msiexec.exe"
    $processInfo.arguments = "/i `"$2Path`" /qr ARGUMENTS"
    $processMSI = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processMSI.StartInfo = $processInfo
    # Write-host $ProcessInfo.arguments
    $processMSI.Start() | Out-Null
    $processMSI.WaitforExit()

    if ($processMSI.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processMSI.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}

# Install 3
if (($choice -eq 3) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Installing 3"
    $3Path = "$InstallSource\Folder3\file.exe"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $3Path
    $processInfo.arguments = "/S /v`" ARGUMENTS`""
    $processEXE = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processEXE.StartInfo = $processInfo
    $processEXE.Start() | Out-Null
    $processEXE.WaitforExit()

    if ($processEXE.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processEXE.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}

# Install 4
if (($choice -eq 4) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Checking for the Desktop-Experience Feature"
    $DEStatus = Get-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience
    if( $DEStatus.Installed -ne "True" ) {
        Write-Host "Installing Desktop-Experience Feature"
        Import-Module ServerManager
        Add-WindowsFeature -Name Desktop-Experience
    }
    Write-Host "Installing 4"
    $4Path = "$InstallSource\Folder4\file.exe"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $4Path
    $processInfo.arguments = "ARGUMENTS"
    $processEXE = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processEXE.StartInfo = $processInfo
    $processEXE.Start() | Out-Null
    $processEXE.WaitforExit()

    if ($processEXE.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processEXE.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }

    # Install 5
    Write-Host "Installing 5"
    $5Path = "$InstallSource\Folder5\file.exe"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $5Path
    $processInfo.arguments = "ARGUMENTS"
    $processEXE = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processEXE.StartInfo = $processInfo
    $processEXE.Start() | Out-Null
    $processEXE.WaitforExit()

    if ($processEXE.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processEXE.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}

# Install 6
if (($choice -eq 3) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Installing 6"
    $6Path = "$InstallSource\Folder6\file.exe"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $6Path
    $processInfo.arguments = "ARGUMENTS"
    $processEXE = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processEXE.StartInfo = $processInfo
    $processEXE.Start() | Out-Null
    $processEXE.WaitforExit()

    if ($processEXE.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processEXE.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}

# Install 7
if (($choice -eq 4) -or ($choice -eq 5)){
    Write-Host "Installing 7"
    $7Path = "$InstallSource\Folder7\file.exe"
    $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $7Path
    $processInfo.arguments = "ARGUMENTS"
    $processEXE = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $processEXE.StartInfo = $processInfo
    $processEXE.Start() | Out-Null
    $processEXE.WaitforExit()

    if ($processEXE.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processEXE.ExitCode "Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}
```

EDIT: Taking TheMadTechnician's code, I simplified it and ran it to see what was happening. Here is the test code:

```
$App1 = "Write-host App1"
$App2 = "Write-host App2"
$App3 = "Write-host App3"
$App4 = "Write-host App4"
$App5 = "Write-host App5"
$App6 = "Write-host App6"
$App7 = "Write-host App7"

# Main Level Menu Choices
$Main_Prompt = '
[1] Choice1
[2] Choice2
[3] Choice3
[4] Choice4
[5] Choice5
[q] Quit
'

switch (Read-Host $Main_Prompt)
    {
        {$_ -eq 1 -or $_ -eq 5} {$ToInstall += $App1}
        {$_ -eq 2 -or $_ -eq 5} {$ToInstall += $App2}
        {$_ -eq 3 -or $_ -eq 5} {$App3,$App4|%{If(!($ToInstall -contains $_)){$ToInstall += $_}}}
        {$_ -eq 4 -or $_ -eq 5} {$App5,$App6,$App7|%{If(!($ToInstall -contains $_)){$ToInstall += $_}}}
        {$_ -ieq "q"} {Write-host "Exiting!";Exit}
    }

ForEach($App in ($ToInstall | Select -Unique)){
    Invoke-Expression $App
}
```

Here is the result (in a code block because I can't post images yet):

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1

[1] Choice1
[2] Choice2
[3] Choice3
[4] Choice4
[5] Choice5
[q] Quit
: 5
App1Write-host App2Write-host App3Write-host App4Write-host App5Write-host App6Write-host App7
PS C:\temp>
```

It appears that the block executes the first command, but then just prints the rest of them to the screen. I'm very much out of my element with this.

Comment: You should replace all your `exit`'s with `break`'s if you don't plan on doing it the way I mentioned at least. Unless you like ISE closing every time you go to test your script. If your into that kinda thing...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't use ISE, but it's probably a better method to use breaks.

Comment: Ok, you are completely changing context here. You are going from objects, with properties, to strings. Plus you completely left out the very first line that declares $ToInstall as an array, so it is being set as a string, and then just adding each new string to the end of the existing string.

Comment: I got it working by removing the pipe to "Select -Unique". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for would be better done like this (reduces code from 158 lines to 43)...

Create an empty array, and define your application paths (or move that to the switch, which may make more sense for you when you see the switch). In the switch create objects that define the title of the application, and the path to the installer for that application. Then do a ForEach loop that selects unique objects and installs them:

```
$ToInstall = @()
$App1 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App1 Name";Path="$InstallSource\Folder1\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder1\file.msi"" /qn-!"}
$App2 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App2 Name";Path="$InstallSource\Folder2\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder2\file.msi"" /qb"}
$App3 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App3 Name";Path = "$InstallSource\Folder3\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder3\file.msi"" /qn"}
$App4 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App4 Name";Path = "$InstallSource\Folder4\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder4\file.msi"" /qb-!"}
$App5 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App5 Name";Path = "$InstallSource\Folder5\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder5\file.msi"" /qn"}
$App6 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App6 Name";Path = "$InstallSource\Folder6\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder6\file.msi"" /qb-! REBOOT=ReallySuppress"}
$App7 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name="App7 Name";Path = "$InstallSource\Folder7\file.msi";Args="/I ""$InstallSource\Folder7\file.msi"" /qr"}

# Main Level Menu Choices
switch (Read-Host $Main_Prompt)
    {
        {$_ -eq 1 -or $_ -eq 5} {$ToInstall += $App1}
        {$_ -eq 2 -or $_ -eq 5} {$ToInstall += $App2}
        {$_ -eq 3 -or $_ -eq 5} {$App3,$App6,$App7|%{If(!($ToInstall -contains $_)){$ToInstall += $_}}}
        {$_ -eq 4 -or $_ -eq 5} {$App4,$App6,$App7|%{If(!($ToInstall -contains $_)){$ToInstall += $_}}}
        {!($_ -ieq "q")} {$ToInstall += $App5}
        {$_ -ieq "q"} {Write-host "Exiting!";Exit}
    }


# Install each app selected

ForEach($App in ($ToInstall |Sort Name)){
    Write-Host $App.Name
    if (Test-Path $App.Path) {
        If($App.Name -eq "App3 Title"){Do stuff to stop service}
        $processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "msiexec.exe"
        $processInfo.arguments = $App.args
        $processMSI = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $processMSI.StartInfo = $processInfo
        $processMSI.Start() | Out-Null
        $processMSI.WaitforExit()

        if ($processMSI.ExitCode -ne 0) {
            Write-Host "The Installer generated error code:" $processMSI.ExitCode "Exiting!"
            exit
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-host "Installer does not exist. Exiting!"
        exit
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Moved creation of objects to before the switch, inserted code to check service on specified application install.

**Edit2:** Updated `$processInfo.arguments =` line, and fixed `$App3`-`$App7` lines. Also re-did how apps are added to the `$ToInstall` array to avoid duplicates and sorted installation order in the ForEach loop.

Comment: That looks great, @TheMadTechnician. I'll put this into my test environment and let you know how it works out. Also, if I wanted to add some code to test that a service is running and then shut it down (I have the working code for this already) but only for a single install option within this loop, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm assuming it has to do with installing a certain application. What I would do is within the ForEach loop add `If($App.Name -eq "Whatever option's title"){Check service and stop it}` before the installation happens.

Comment: I can do that. Also, the Arguments are different for each application. Should I set those as variables under the $ToInstall array as well and put them in the switch block?

Comment: Yeah, just add another property to the custom object, such as `[PSCustomObject]@{Name="Name";Path=$1Path;Args="/I ""$($App.Path)"" /qr"}` (notice the double double-quotes, that's an alternative to having to escape them with a backtick)

Comment: Awesome. Also need a way to differential the paths from .exe and .msi. This will change the way the Code block works. If they are .exe, then the ProcessInfo target will be the exe instead of msiexec.exe. Thinking about a simple if statement with another variable... Is there a way to select the last three characters of the path as the test then change the process target to either the path variable or msiexec.exe?

Comment: `If($App.Path -match "exe$"){This is an EXE} else {This is not an EXE}` ...also updated answer to reflect some of what we have discussed. And I moved the creation of object outside the switch to make things easier to manage down the road.

Comment: This hit the nail on the head. I did some tweaking and added this back into the "real" code and it tested beautifully. I will be putting the full script on my blog once I've tested some more and I'll link to it in the original post. THANKS!

Comment: Actually... Spoke too soon. The lines with two and three applications are only installing the first app. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was my fault I think. I updated the answer, and notated what I updated for you.

Comment: Updated my question with test code and results to display problem with your example. I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that calls itself until a valid response is given.

```
Function Get-Response {
    Param ($Main_Prompt)
    switch (Read-Host $Main_Prompt) {
        1 {1}
        2 {2}
        3 {3}
        4 {4}
        5 {5}
        "q" {'q'}
        Default {Get-Response @PSBoundParameters}
    }
}

$Value = Get-Response -Main_Prompt 'Do Something'
Write-Verbose "Value: $Value given" -Verbose
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the opposite of what the question is asking for. And the script breaks when you give it anything that isn't 1-5 or q

Comment: This is a loop, just like the OP asked, just not done using a Do/While statement. The function will keep calling itself until it receives valid input. What part breaks for you? I tested on a couple consoles (PowerShell V3) without issue. The Default is there to catch any bad responses.

Comment: this is not a loop, it's a recursive function. And it did break before you added `@PSBoundParameters` . But no where in the question does it mention anything about waiting for a valid response...

Comment: Sure, it is a recursive function, but it still prompts for user input until a response is given that matches the available selections.