# Menus and submenus

Tags: powershell, loops, menu, submenu

Main menu:

```
1 Delete
2 Create
3 Modify
4 Remove
X Exit
```

Submenu 1 (for Delete):

```
1 Delete file
2 Delete folder
3 Delete another file
4 Delete another folder
5 Back to Main Menu
```

Submenu 2 (for Create):

```
1 Create Virtual
2 Create another Virtual
3 Back to Main Menu
```

Submenu 3 (for Modify):

```
1 Modify Virtual
2 Modify another Virtual
3 Back to Main Menu
```

This is the main menu:

```
$q = Read-Host "
Please select an option:
1 Delete Files 
2 Create New Virtual
3 Modify Existing Virtual
"
```

Sub-Menu1

```
$su1 = Read-Host "
Please select an option
1 Delete a file
2 Delete a folder
3 Delete another file
4 Delete another folder
5 Back to main menu
"
```

How do I take option 5 and bring it back to the main menu?

Comment: Put the submenus in functions, put the main menu in a loop, and call the submenu functions from that loop.

Comment: Similar to this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515365/creating-a-for-loop-to-consolidate-powershell-menu-driven-script

Comment: Not exactly. More [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625434/1630171), only that the submenus go in functions with loops of their own. Note that there are [several ways of creating a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890047/1630171) in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create functions for each menu going through a switch so that you could keep calling new menus

```
function mainMenu(){
    clear
    switch(Read-Host "1 Delete
2 Create
3 Modify
4 Remove
X Exit"){
        X {break}
        2 {createMenu}
        default {"N/A"}
    }
}

function createMenu(){
    clear
    switch(Read-Host "Please select an option `
1 Delete a file
2 Delete a folder
3 Delete another file
4 Delete another folder
5 Back to main menu"){
        5 {mainMenu}
        default {"N/A"}
    }
}

mainMenu
```