# Options Menu For Script

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a powershell script, and need to know how to add an options menu to the script which will send people to different sections of the script.

It's for user creation, so i need an option menu for creating AD users via a CSV file or creating a user from inputted data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menus and submenus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672797/menus-and-submenus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Read-Host` to accept some user input. I've also embedded this into a `While` loop so that if invalid input is entered it keeps prompting. Then use a `Switch` statement to go to different code functions depending on what option was selected (or you could just embed the code in the `switch` directly if you'd prefer):

```
Function New-UserFromCSV {
    #User from CSV code..
}

Function New-UserManual {
    #User manual input code..
}


Write-Host 'Create AD user:

  1. From CSV
  2. via Manual input
  q. Quit'


While (($Selection = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please select an option') -notin 1,2,'q') 
{ 
    Write-Warning "$Selection is not a valid option" 
}

Switch ($Selection) {
    1 { New-UserFromCSV }
    2 { New-UserManual }
}
```

It's worth noting that this sort of menu driven UI isn't necessarily where PowerShell shines, and it would be better to make functions that accept parameter inputs and then just educate your users on how to use those functions in the same way as they might use other PowerShell cmdlets.

But if a menu is absolutely what you want/need the above should get you going.

Comment: Cheers Mate, looks to be working.

I'm running in powershell as it's only for my colleagues and I to use. My manager requested that I expand my script out, to run both scripts within a single script instead of two different scripts.

Comment: Actually, ran into an issue with it.

It states that 'New-UserManual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'

However, it is put in as a function.

Comment: It has to be declared before you use it, so generally its best to put functions at the top of your script. My guess is you've put them after as that probably seemed logical from a "this code gets executed next.." perspective.

Comment: I did indeed. That makes sense though, let me test that haha.